# Stander "s" Specifier in DateTime Class

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In `DateTime` "s" Stander Specifier there is some points I can not understand them form Microsoft documentation of C#.

> The purpose of the "s" format specifier is to produce result strings
>   that sort consistently in ascending or descending order based on date
>   and time values.

How Can "s" Specifier sort a value for `DateTime` in ascending or descending order?

> Although the "s" standard format specifier represents a date and time
>   value in a consistent format, the formatting operation does not modify
>   the value of the date and time object that is being formatted to
>   reflect its `DateTime.Kind` property or its `DateTimeOffset.Offset` value.

What is mean by "modify the value of the date and time object that is being formatted to reflect its `DateTime.Kind` property"?

Cloud any one help me in these two questions...

Comment: When you format the `DateTime` using `s`, it doesn't change the original `DateTime` object

Comment: It doesnt say `s` sorts anything.  It says the **result** can be sorted.  The second one means it doesnt change anything about the DateTime value.  Keep in mind formatting is **not** about the DateTime or its value but the **string** which is created

Comment: @Plutonix - For the first one how the result can be sorted ?

Comment: It is for the case where you had a collection of things with a date field.  Note that an actual DateTime value/property is perfectly sortable as is though

Comment: @Plutonix - Well I've got the idea but how can I control the **sort** of collection of `DateTime` values in terms of whether ascending or descending using this specifier

Comment: Thats a different question.  Formatting a date results in a new string `2008-04-10T06:30:00` for example for `s` as MSDN shows.  If that was part of a collection of objects, the collection could be sorted according to the date.  e.g. linq: `myCol.OrderBy{x => x.TheDate)`

Comment: @Plutonix - In the second one I think all Specifiers does not change the value of `DateTime` objects, instead producing new string with specific format (as string result). Is there is anything **special** about this Specifier since not all Specifiers have this Kind of note in Microsoft documentation

Comment: The NET DateTime type is immutable, so *nothing* ever changes them: AddDays, AddTicks, SpecifyKind all create a new DateTime var.  `ToString` is an obvious type conversion as the name hints at; but what the note means (in part) is that the DateTime value is not changed as a part of the string formatting